# Move specific extension files and check for duplicate to change name if there is

Tags: powershell

I try to build a function to move file with a specific extension and I want to check if there is a duplicate file in the destination repo. When I run this script it seem's like it go directly to else when I setup a copy of the file to move from source to destination in the destination. Could someone explain me why and how to fix it

```
   function deplacer_dossier {
    
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers *.mp3
            Foreach ($file in $files) 
            {
                $fileexists = Test-Path C:\mestp\media\audio\$file
                if($fileexists) {
                    $i = 1
                    $NewName = $file.BaseName + "_" + $i + $file.extension
                    $NewName | Move-Item -Destination "C:\mestp\media\audio"
                }
                else {
                    $file | Move-Item -Destination "C:\mestp\media\audio"
                }    
            }
    
    }



Move-Item: D:\Documents\AEC Réseautique & Cybersécurité\420-E17-RI PROJET INTÉGRATEUR\TP1_Part1.ps1:43:25
Line |
  43 |                  $file | Move-Item -Destination "C:\mestp\media\audio"
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Comment: One issue is there may already be a file with that number, you’re not checking if the new name exists

Comment: As Doug stated above, what's happening in your `foreach` loop should be a `while` or `do` loop that produces a new file name until `Test-Path` returns `$false`

Comment: Also, `$NewName = $file.BaseName + "_" + $i + $file.extension` should be part of the Destination Path instead of the file you're moving